# Accessing All Imports without Knowing their Assigned Variable Names

Tags: javascript, import, scoping, es6-modules

Is it possible to access **all** values that were assigned to variables by **all** import statements, without using the variable-names that were assigned by those import statements?

```
import { module1 } from './module1.mjs';
import { module2 } from './module2.mjs';
// . . .
import { module500 } from './module500.mjs';
```

Imagine a list of 500 imports like above, but assume that the variable names are not as predictable as above.

In the scope of the "module importing these imports", is it possible to access all values ("that were assigned to variables" during all imports) by somthing like `consumingModule.imports[index]` instead of accessing each value using the variable name?

I realize that I could manually add each module-variable to an array like this:

```
let ary = [];
ary.push(module1);
ary.push(module2);
// . . .
ary.push(module500);
```

But, I'm hoping that ecmascript already has a module-level-scope-object (kind of like `this`) where it is possible to access all imported values via an array instead of having to explicitly specify each variable-name like I'm doing to create the ary (above).

Comment: the names are lexical, not attached to an object. best bet might be to ajax in the module file and parse the imports with a regexp.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, but perhaps `import * as foo from './foo'; Object.keys(foo)` will do the job?

Comment: @dandavis: console.log(this) in a module is undefined. Is there any object that is module-scope? If I var a variable, is that too lexical from within a module?

Comment: you're right, there's no global _this_ in modules, cleaning up a long-standing flaw/risk in JS. Just like local vars, there's no easy way to iterate all defined variables, including ones that happen to be imported. You also can't wrap an importer in a function, so you can't hack out a function wrapper's .toString() to sniff defined variables, so the only way, afaik, would be to fetch() the module url (which may have to be hard-coded since document.currentScript is null inside modules) and parse/match the declarations...

Comment: maybe you can wrap something along the lines of the runtime interface: `import("/module1.mjs").then( fnSomethingHere )` ?

Comment: @dandavis: I'm fine with there not being a global `this` in modules, but I'm not yet sure there shouldn't be a module-level `this` in modules. They've made it hard as hell to automate processing you want done to each imported module.

Comment: @dandavis : [import.meta](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_modules.html#preview-import.meta.url) is an ECMAScript feature that holds metadata for the current module. You might think it would contain an accessible list of imports, but if you console.log(import.meta) it only has one property ("url").

Comment: well, the url is at least a foot in the door; the least they can do i suppose... if you have consistency, a regexp might be enough to accomplish your particular task, but to support the whole arbitrary possibilities, you might need a full-blown es parser (yikes)

Answer (score 1):

Would it work to use Object.keys:

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-microservice-v2z27

Comment: `this` is undefined in modules, making `Object.keys(this)` not an option.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand^..?

Comment: In your example, you are using the variable name ("React"). Using the variable-name is off limits in my question. The whole point is to get an array of all values imported from all modules (not just one), and to do so without using any of the variable names that were assigned by the import statements (500 import statements).

Comment: I see. In that case, I'm confident there isn't something built into ecmascript that will give you that, natively.

Comment: You mostly can't do things programmatically with import; not until they finalize dynamic import; ECMAScript ES2020; https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import

Answer (score 1):

You mostly can't do things programmatically with import; not until they finalize dynamic import; ECMAScript ES2020; v8.dev/features/dynamic-import

But you can do programmatic things with `require`. If you were not opposed to `require` versus `import` & you could control across the board how modules are consumed, you could create your own implementation of what you are looking for.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-microservice-v2z27